# setup timed out when creating an insert() function in a custom Vector class

Tags: c++

I faced this error

```
  [ 20%] Built target support
  [ 80%] Built target probLib1
  [ 90%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/vector_insert.dir/vector_insert.cpp.o
  [100%] Linking CXX executable vector_insert
  [100%] Built target vector_insert
  
❌ vector_insert
::error::Setup timed out in 60000 milliseconds
```

when I was trying to build a custom Vector class and define an insert() function.

```
private:
    T* ifmt; 
    int vsize;
    int vcap;
```

```
void insert(int index, const T& item) // insert element
    {
        push_back(item); // ?
        for (int i = vsize - 1; i > index; --i)
        {
            ifmt[i] = ifmt[i - 1];
        }      
        ifmt[index] = item;     
        
    }

void push_back(const T& item) // append element // send element to the end
    {
      if (vsize == vcap) 
      {
        T* ttemp = new T[2 * vcap]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < vsize; ++i) 
        {
            ttemp[i] = ifmt[i];
        }
        delete [] ifmt; 
        vcap = vcap * 2; 
        ifmt = ttemp; 
      }
      ifmt[vsize] = item; 
      vsize = vsize + 1; 
    }
```

I assume this is caused by

```
push_back(item);
```

yet I have no clue how to solve it.

I have searched for a long while but it seems there is no similar case published. The existing ones have nothing to do with my case.
[C++: Program crash while adding object to custom vector class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103722/c-program-crash-while-adding-object-to-custom-vector-class)
[Insert method in custom vector class in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809590/insert-method-in-custom-vector-class-in-c)

Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: Did you get the error while compiling or while running the program? It isn't clear from that output. Can you make this a [mcve] that can be copy/pasted and tested?

Comment: Did you initialize the private members of your class? They might have random values.

Comment: You need to provide your driver code in the main function.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys I finally find out this is caused by the initialization of member variables, or to be specific, the default constructor of this Vector class.

The original one:

```
Vector(int size = 0, const T& value = T{}) // construct by default / given size
{
  vsize = size;
  vcap = size * 2; 
  ifmt = new T[vcap];
  for (int i = 0; i < vsize; ++i)
  {
    ifmt[i] = value;
  }
}
```

The edited version:

```
Vector(int size = 0, const T& value = T{}) // construct by default / given size
{
  vsize = size;
  vcap = size + 1; // edited
  ifmt = new T[vcap];
  for (int i = 0; i < vsize; ++i)
  {
    ifmt[i] = value;
  }
}
```

Although I have no clue why it should be like this, it works well lol

Comment: This is not how you should initialize members, you should initialize them before the body of your main.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor, and those initializations MUST happen in the same order your member variables have been declared.

Comment: Other note use std::vector<T>, [R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly). Or if you must allocate manually then at least use std::make_unique. When you use `std::vector<T> ifmt`, your member initialization becomes `ifmt(size,value);` and your for loop is gone as well.